# StateMachine validation failing

Tags: statemachines, validation, error

Transition function throws an error. Here it is.

```
transition :: FreelanceContract -> State FContractDatum -> FContractRedeemer -> Maybe (TxConstraints Void Void, State FContractDatum)
transition fc s r =
    case (stateValue s, stateData s, r) of
        _ -> Just (Constraints.mustBeSignedBy (freelancer fc) , State (FContractDatum 1 (Just 0)) (lovelaceValueOf 2))
```

Here is the wallet code for submitting the transaction

```
    case m of
        Nothing             -> throwError "Contract ouput not found"
        Just ((o, _), _) -> case tyTxOutData o of

            FContractDatum 0 Nothing -> do
                logInfo @String "Contract found. Accepting..."
                void $ mapError' $ runStep client Accept
                logInfo @String "Contract Accepted"

            _ -> throwError "unexpected datum"
```

And here is the error that is thrown when I run my trace.
[image]

I have boiled this code down to its simplest parts, but still, the error persists. :/

Comment: How about troubleshooting by replacing `Constraints.mustBeSignedBy (freelancer fc)` with `mempty`? The Wallet sending the transaction might not belong to `freelancer fc`

Comment: I tried that too! Same error. Maybe my StateMachine setup is where the bug is...

Comment: Did you implement the `smCheck` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most probably caused by an omitted `check` function. Even if you do not use it, you have to specify it.

Example:

```
check :: FreelanceContract -> FContractDatum -> FContractRedeemer -> ScriptContext -> Bool
check _ _ _ _ = True

...

fCStateMachine :: FreelanceContract -> StateMachine FContractDatum FContractRedeemer
fCStateMachine fc = StateMachine
{ smTransition = transition fc
, smFinal = final
, smCheck = check fc
, smThreadToken = blah blah
}
```

with the assumption that the function pointing to your final state is `final` and your `ThreadToken` "blah blah" :)

Comment: Great minds think alike ;)

Comment: True that!!! xD

Answer (score 2):

My StateMachine does not need any additional checks with the smCheck so I completely removed the field. The compiler complained only a little bit and gave me a warning that I had an uninitialized field. Turns out, this field is required for any transitions to be valid.

I added in this function which always returns True and the error was fixed.

```
check :: FContractDatum -> FContractRedeemer -> ScriptContext -> Bool
check _ _ _ = True
```